# Adding add_index breaks 'times' iterator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, indexing, rspec, factory-bot

When I add this to my migration file, it breaks an rspec test:

migration:

```
add_index :SurveyResponses, [:ID, :QuestionID, :AnswerID, :LastEditedTimestamp ], unique: true, name: 'short_sr'
```

rspec test:

```
5.times do |index|
  @org.survey_responses << create(:survey_response)
end
```

When the add_index is commented out however, it does not break.
When I am inside a pry and I just enter in `@org.survey_responses << create(:survey_response)` it also does not break. It only breaks when I use the 5.times iterator.

Error message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '18001-EML_Organization_ProductSurvey-InstitutionProvidesLayPension' for key 'short_sr': UPDATE `SurveyResponses` SET `BlahOID` = 18001, `OrganizationOID` = 18001 WHERE `SurveyResponses`.`ResponseID` = 33014
```

note: I changed up the names here, but don't worry about them

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Its a MySQL duplicate entry error 


```ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '18001-EML_Organization_ProductSurvey-InstitutionProvidesLayPension' for key 'short_sr': UPDATE `SurveyResponses` SET `BlahOID` = 18001, `OrganizationOID` = 18001 WHERE `SurveyResponses`.`ResponseID` = 33014```   

I'm assuming I need to sequence the 'short_sr' column some how?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming in your factory you have a static value set for short_sr, or it is currently being generated in some way that allows duplicates to be created.